# DropDownListFor from Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This probably has been asked over a thousand times already but I just can't get my head around this after trying it for over 10 times.

I'm trying to create a 'Teacher' where one can select a Division the teacher is in.

Model:

```
public class CreateTeacherModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Division")]
    public Division Division { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Divisions")]
    public Dictionary<Guid, Division> Divisions
    {
        get
        {
            var db = new IBPVEntities();

            Division = db.Division.FirstOrDefault();

            return db.Division.ToDictionary(division => division.DivisionId);
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult CreateTeacherTest()
    {
        return View(new CreateTeacherModel());
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateTeacherTest(CreateTeacherModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var selectedDivision = model.Division;
            // Save to database.
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Division, new SelectList(Model.Divisions, "DivisionId", "Name"))
```

Division has 2 properties: DivisionId (guid) and Name (string).

I totally lost track on what to do now, can someone help me out on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and what is the problem ? what is it not working for you ?

Answer (score 3):

To "settle" Division as you inidcated is quite simple.  In your model (CreateTeacherModel), you would not actually use Division as the property type, but instead use Guid:

```
public Guid DivisionId { get; set; }
```

and in your controller, do a lookup to get the actual Division:

```
db.Divisions.First(x => x.Id == Model.DivisionId);
```

If you need to transform the CreateTeacherModel into an Entity Framework object, you could look into [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to do the transformation for you (that is how Stack Overflow does it behind the scenes).

If you feel like getting fancy, you could register a custom model binder.  see [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Division, 
    new SelectList(
        Model.Divisions.ToList().Select(
            x => new { Value = x.Value.DivisionId, Text = x.Value.Name }
        ), 
        "Value", 
        "Text"
    )
)
```

or you could add a property to your view model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DivisionsList
{
    get
    {
        return Divisions.ToList().Select(
            x => new SelectListItem 
            { 
                Value = x.Value.DivisionId.ToString(), 
                Text = x.Value.Name 
            }
        );
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Division, Model.DivisionsList)
```

or yet another property is not to use a dictionary at all in your view model but directly:

```
[Display(Name = "Divisions")]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Divisions
{
    get
    {
        var db = new IBPVEntities();
        Division = db.Division.FirstOrDefault();
        return db.Division.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.DivisionId.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
        });
    }
}
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Division, Model.Divisions)
```

Comment: Thanks! that helped me a big deal, although... Division doesn't seem to be setted when I get to the post?